# Is there a way to disable/enable elements in a javaFx application on the startup of said application, i.e Panes and buttons

Tags: java, button, javafx, pane

Ok so this is the first question I've asked on StackOverflow so apologies if its unclear.

Basically, I am making a program in **JavaFx** that is an ordering system for a fake Cafe. Its for an assignment and it really doesn't have to make conventional sense because my curriculum doesn't really care if it is actually useful or not, they just want to see you code some random stuff.

Anyways, the problem i am having atm is that I am trying to make it so when I open the Main page called MainPage.fxml, 4 things will be pre-disabled/enabled. These elements are PinPane Which contains the sign-in buttons and labels), PrimaryPane (which contains all buttons leading to different ordering pages), SettingsBtn (Sends user to settings), and LogoutBtn (Self expanatory).

This is important because when the program is first opened, MainPage is the first thing that is started. Once a user Signs in, and heads off to another page to select an item however, when they come back to the MainPage, where the current-order is displayed in PrimaryPage (I haven't actually done any code for that yet), I want to ensure that the disabled/enabled states of all 4 elements remains the same as when user left to go to another Page.

Currently, I am using a static class called DataContainer.java, which contains all data shared by the program, and I thought i could put 3 boolean variables which basically just tell the program on the opening of MainPage what is disabled and enabled.

However, my Primary problem is, I can't seem to be able to change the state of any of these elements on startup, and i have no idea how to do that other wise.

My code for the MainPageController.java is below:

'''

```
public class MainPageController {

   @FXML private Label Price; //fx:if -> Price

   @FXML public  Pane PrimaryPage, PinPane; //fx:id -> PrimaryPage

   @FXML public  Label Pin; //fx:id -> Pin

   @FXML public  Button LogoutBtn, SettingsBtn;



   public void Check(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

  // This is the method I use to check the entered pin against current 
  // saved pins. 

       DataContainer.DataContainer();
       // This is just a method i use for testing, it adds a manager account that i can sign in with 
       // each time the program is opened because I haven't introduced account creation and saving 
       // yet

       int pin = Integer.parseInt(Pin.getText());

       int i = DataContainer.Users.size();
       int x = 0;
       while (x <= i-1){
           if (DataContainer.Users.get(x).PinNumber == pin){

           // In this, once the pin is verified, each element is enabled and disabled, and the 
           // boolean variables are set as well for future use

                System.out.println("test");
                DataContainer.UserIndex = x;
                PrimaryPage.setDisable(false);
                LogoutBtn.setDisable(false);
                DataContainer.PrimaryPage = true;
                Pin.setText("");
                PinPane.setDisable(true);
                DataContainer.PinPane = false;
                break;

           }
           x = x + 1;
       }

       if (DataContainer.Users.get(DataContainer.UserIndex).Position.equals("Manager")){

           SettingsBtn.setDisable(false);
           DataContainer.SettingsBtn = true;

        }
```

'''

This is the code for DataContainer.java

'''

```
public class DataContainer{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    }

    public static void DataContainer(){
        Users.add(owner); 
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    static boolean PinPane = true, PrimaryPage  = false, SettingsBtn = false; 
    // These boolean values are relevant to the MainPage application
    // Their purpose is to retain the information of the state in which the user
    // left the main page, i.e, if the PinPage is disabled, the PrimaryPage is enabled, etc.
    // this is important as if these variables don't exist the MainPage and its elements
    // go back to their default state and the user has to re-sign in.

    static String firstname, lastname, position;
    static int PinNo, PhoneNo, UserIndex;

    public static UserVariables user = new UserVariables(firstname, lastname, position, PinNo, 
    PhoneNo);

    static UserVariables owner = new UserVariables("Test", "User", "Manager", 1234, 
    0434553);


    public static ArrayList<UserVariables> Users = new ArrayList<UserVariables>();

    }
```

'''

And finally this is the code for FInalIA.java (Main class):

'''

```
public class FInalIA extends Application implements Serializable {

     public static void main(String args[]) {

     launch(args);

     }


     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainPage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Main Page");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        stage.show();

        MainPageController.Open();

    }

  }
```

'''

And Finally, this is the code i was thinking of using, by making a public static method called 'Open()', and making all the panes static, and just just calling this method when ever MainPage is opened.

'''

```
public static void Open(){
    if (DataContainer.PinPane == false){
        PinPane.setDisable(true);
    }

    else{
        PinPane.setDisable(false);
    }

    if(DataContainer.PrimaryPage == false){
        PrimaryPage.setDisable(true);
        LogoutBtn.setDisable(true);
    }

    else{
        PrimaryPage.setDisable(false);
        LogoutBtn.setDisable(false);
    }

    if(DataContainer.SettingsBtn == false){
        SettingsBtn.setDisable(true);
    }

    else{
        SettingsBtn.setDisable(false);
    }

}
```

'''

Thanks to whoever helps me out with this (Also can you guys plz tell me if what i am writing is to non-concise and irrelevant or if its actually good)

Comment: You don't need the '''s because the formatted code gets highlighted anyways. The instances of your classes should start with lower case and you probably should not be using a static reference to MainPage to call open. Is anything happening when you call open? Also, you do not need all of the comments in your pasted code.

Comment: You can disable the panes in the FXML file with `disable="true"` attributes. Or you could give your controller an `@FXML void initialize() { ... }` method and disable the panes there, assuming you've configured them to be injected. And unrelated: Please follow [Java naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming)—field, parameter, variable, and method names all use `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Step one make Open non-static. You're going to create an instance of your controller and it will manage the associated items.

```
public class MainPageController implements Initializable{
   @FXML private Label price; //fx:if -> Price
   @FXML public  pane primaryPage, pinPane; //fx:id -> PrimaryPage
   @FXML public  Label pin; //fx:id -> Pin
   @FXML public  button bogoutBtn, settingsBtn;

   public void Check(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
       //why is this method included but not open?
   }
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
       if (DataContainer.PinPane == false){
           pinPane.setDisable(true);
       } else{
           pinPane.setDisable(false);
       }
       primaryPage.setDisable( ! DataContainer.PrimaryPage );
       logoutBtn.setDisable(! DataContainer.PrimaryPage);
       //etc etc      
    }
}
```

I've made your controller implement Initializable, that way it has a method initialize that gets called when you start. I've also improved the naming, eg `Pin` should be named `pin`. If this doesn't work for you, I can replace this with a small enclosed example.

You don't need to implement [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) javafx will automatically call an appropriate initialize method.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll try that out tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Comment: There's no need to make the controller implement `Initializable`: you just need an `initialize(...)` method, either with no-args, or with the signature you've declared it with here.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I didn't realize it wasn't necessary. It does add some compile-time check though by including it `@Override`

Comment: @matt, what do you mean exactly by my check() method not being open? What is that referring to?

Comment: @matt, also what exactly does 'URL url' and 'ResourceBundle rb' refer to?, and am i supposed to call this method on the creation of MainPage or is there an automatic method call?

Comment: @G0mena you included the method `check` but you had `Open` separate. Check isn't really necessary. `URL` and `ResourceBundle` are arguments that javafx uses, [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) you don't need them.

Comment: @matt oh sorry man I'm super stupid, I legit forgot i had a method called open so i was v confused as to what open was referring to. Anyways i used your method and did some extra digging and made the program essentially work, thanks so much my dude you are an absolute legend

Comment: @G0mena no worries, it is confusing since open has other means.